# Can I make an SVG stretch to the width of the parent while preserving the aspectRatio?

Tags: svg

I need this SVG to be positioned right bottom, so I used xMaxYMin. But that disables it's ability to be the width of the parent . Is there any way to keep it's ratio but also be the width of the parent?